# Identify Rows with Same ID but different Values in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with user License Details. And there are cases where I have multiple rows for a same user but with different License type. I want to Identify the users who have Admin License via DAX Calculated Column.

Eg: My table will be like this where User A has multiple rows with 1 Admin License
[image: Sample Table] 
 
 
And I am expecting a result like this where User A is marked as True for all his Row enteries
[image: Expected Result]

So in short I want to Flag the user as True on all his rows if he has at least one Admin License.

I hope my explanation was clear.  
 
 
Have a good day !!! 
Best Regards, 
Pratik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display all Trues when the user has at least one admin right, first you need to create a index column using the following formula:

```
index = IF(Sheet1[License]="Admin",1,0)
```

Next, based on the result of the index column then you will be able to display the correct output with following formula:

```
status = 
var index1 = CALCULATE(SUM(Sheet1[index]),
    FILTER(Sheet1,Sheet1[User]=EARLIER(Sheet1[User])))
return
IF(index1 > 0,"True","False")
```

**Table result:**

[image]

Comment: Welcome, glad you find it useful :)